# Where doe the init code go in AWS C++ lambda functions?

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

The AWS Lambda docs emphasize the importance of [static initialization](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/operatorguide/static-initialization.html); the example code is in Python. My question is where initialization code goes in a C++ function (using the [AWS C++ runtime](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-lambda-cpp)).

The S3 example seems relevant (quoted below). If it's possible to do my expensive initialization code in `main()`, and then pass any relevant objects to a (C++) lambda function, then that's the answer to my question. I'm just uncertain how AWS uses the C++ code.

```
int main()
{
    using namespace Aws;
    SDKOptions options;
    options.loggingOptions.logLevel = Aws::Utils::Logging::LogLevel::Trace;
    options.loggingOptions.logger_create_fn = GetConsoleLoggerFactory();
    InitAPI(options);
    {
        Client::ClientConfiguration config;
        config.region = Aws::Environment::GetEnv("AWS_REGION");
        config.caFile = "/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt";

        auto credentialsProvider = Aws::MakeShared<Aws::Auth::EnvironmentAWSCredentialsProvider>(TAG);
        S3::S3Client client(credentialsProvider, config);
        auto handler_fn = [&client](aws::lambda_runtime::invocation_request const& req) {
            return my_handler(req, client);
        };
        run_handler(handler_fn);
    }
    ShutdownAPI(options);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can pass variables by reference or by copy into the lambda. If you have lots of context like this you can group them in a class and make `my_handler` a method of that class.

Comment: And where would I delete my pointers? Where it has `ShutdownAPI(options);` above? Or should I just not worry about that?

Comment: Anytime you want after `run_handler` returns.